# Like and Not like on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run this query on Sql server mgmt studio where Like and not Like statment to be used on the same column on same query 
I want to know all the records where there is a Final reminder notice sent but no NTK letter has not been sent for all the records.It gives me same result as  for ----like '%Final Reminder%'

```
select [rjvn_pound_reference],[rjvn_time],[rjvn_userid] ,[rjvn_note] FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] where removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note  not like '%NTK%'

select  [rjvn_pound_reference],[rjvn_time],[rjvn_userid],[rjvn_note]  
FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] where removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note   like '%Final Reminder%'
```

This is my query:

```
select  [rjvn_pound_reference],[rjvn_time],[rjvn_userid],[rjvn_note]  
    FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] where
 removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note   like '%Final Reminder%' and 
  removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note  not like '%NTK%
```

DATA :

rjvn_pound_reference rjvn_time rjvn_userid rjvn_note

```
1109225 24/03/2015 11:23:01 JEMMAT  Drive off final reminder sent
1110236 12/03/2015 10:20:03 KATIEB  Drive off- Final reminder sent
1110359 25/03/2015 13:07:39 KATIEB  Drive off- Final reminder notice 
1110996 20/03/2015 09:11:09 JEMMAT  Drive off final reminder sent
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Are there any records that match the first query that *should not* match the second one, but do?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to check over multiple rows. Then you need to split into two queries connected by a NOT EXISTS, e.g. if you want to check for each `[rjvn_userid]`:

```
select  [rjvn_pound_reference],[rjvn_time],[rjvn_userid],[rjvn_note]  
FROM [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] as t1 
where removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note  like '%Final Reminder%' 
and not exists
 ( 
   select * from [ICPS].[dbo].[removal_job_vehicle_notes] as t2
   where t1.[rjvn_userid] = t2.[rjvn_userid]
   and removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note like '%NTK%
 )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
where
    (removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note like '%Final Reminder%')
    and not (removal_job_vehicle_notes.rjvn_note like '%NTK%')
```

Comment: `not like` is the same as `not (like)`.